# Parse page to get input and then submit post including this input value

Tags: php, curl

I want to parse page where is form and this form includes token input
need to take this token value and send with my inputs

this is curl code what i was using before they added token input

```php
$username = @$_POST['user'];
$password = @$_POST['password'];
$to = @$_POST['to'];
$text = @$_POST['text'];    
$loginUrl = '';
$sendUrl = '';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$username&password=$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch)."/n";
}
//sending
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sendUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "recipients=$to&message_body=$text");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name-send'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie-send.txt');
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch)."/n";
}
echo $answer;
```

This is page what i want to parse

```html
<form name="user_action" method="post" action="index.php?page=11&amp;lang=ge">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="7e71ea58eaaa55986b0fdc71b2d44c92">    
<input type="text" id="user" name="user" class="round_border medium_box">
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="round_border medium_box">
<input type="submit" value="შესვლა" class="btn red_btn round_border medium">
</form>
```

No i can't post without this token `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="7e71ea58eaaa55986b0fdc71b2d44c92">`

And all i need is to to parse this page first to get token and same time send post with this token

Answer (score 1):

Check out DOMDocument for parsing HTML. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Here's what I'd try:

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents("https://wherever-the-form-is.com");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $page );

// Get a list of all inputs
$inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'input' );
$total = $inputs->length;
$token = false;

// Loop through inputs looking for one with the right name
for( $i = 0; $i < $total; $i++ ) {
    if ( $inputs->item($i)->getAttribute('name') == 'csrf_token' ) {
        // When you find the right name, record the value and break out of the loop
        $token = $inputs->item($i)->getAttribute('value');
        break;
    }
}

if ( $token ) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Obviously, some more error handling would need to be put into action. Like what if `$page` was empty or DOMDocument wasn't able to parse it?

Comment: dude you should learn DOMXPath :) all that can be replaced by `$token=(new DOMXPath($dom))->query("//input[@name='csrf_token']")->item(0)->getAttribute("value");`

Answer (score 0):

@Stevish is correct, you should be using DOMDocument, but i suggest a slightly different approach: loop all input children of the form instead, eg

```
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($answer);
$xp=new DOMXPath($domd);
$inputs=array();
foreach($xp->query("//form[@name='user_action']//input") as $input){
    $inputs[$input->getAttribute("name")]=$input->getAttribute("value");
}
```

that should leave you with

```
$inputs=array (
  'csrf_token' => '7e71ea58eaaa55986b0fdc71b2d44c92',
  'user' => '',
  'password' => '',
  '' => 'á¨áá¡ááá',
)
```

.. also you're encoding $to nor $message here, what do you think will happen if $message contains `blabla&to=moreblabla` ? it would overwrite your previous $to and make your $to variable irrelevant, you need to url-encode that shit, so either

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "recipients=".urlencode($to)."&message_body=".urlencode($text));
```

or better yet, use http_build_query,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(
    array(
        "recipients" => $to,
        "message_body" => $text
    )
));
```

... or even better,

```
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($answer);
$xp=new DOMXPath($domd);
$inputs=array();
foreach($xp->query("//form[@name='user_action']//input") as $input){
    $inputs[$input->getAttribute("name")]=$input->getAttribute("value");
}
$inputs["recipients"]=$to;
$inputs["message_body"]=$text;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($inputs));
```